# My array won't print when loading app (viewDidLoad)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I feel like a total muppet but I can't seem to get an array to print when loading the app I'm making, however I've done it before with Ints and other variables. What have I done wrong. I feel like I'm going backwards rather than forwards when learning lol.

I have the following code, but it won't print to the console when I run the code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var arrayLocations:[[Double]] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrayLocations.append([27.1750199, 78.0399665])

    print("\(arrayLocations[0][0]) and \(arrayLocations[0][1])")

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I should ask complex questions and not this.

I'm trying to make an app and I need to access the variable in one view controller from another.

And yes, I did my searches and still couldn't work out what's wrong...

Thanks for any help.

Edit: This is my xcode screen.

[image: Xcode screen shot]

[image: with the identity inspector]

Comment: There is no problem with the code. Is this your initial view controller?

Comment: It is. And yes, I can't see anything wrong with it either however there's nothing that shows in the console when I load the app initially or when I go back to that view controller from another one.

Comment: Are you using story board?

Comment: Yes. You mean it might be a fault in the Main.storyboard showing which is the main view controller?

Comment: Are you sure that your view controller in your storyboard is connected to this class?

Comment: Keep a break point and see if the execution reaches the ViewDidLoad method. If not check if the class has been set in the Identity Inspector for that View Controller

Comment: I added a screen shot above if that helps? And I'll put a breakpoint and see, good idea.

Comment: Huh, you're right! It didn't run viewDidLoad

Comment: The screenshot does not show the Identity Inspector. Can you select the ViewController (Interface builder) and share the screenshot of the Identity Inspector

Comment: I'm really confused. @Sam_M and rshankar, you were both right. That particular view controller has not had it's class set, but I can't change it. The ViewController does not come up as an option and I can't change it manually. I'm really confused...

Comment: It's because in the story board "Places" is a table view controller but your ViewController class is not a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: @Sam_M and how do I change that?

Comment: @rshankar I've added the screen shot.

Comment: You need to change `class ViewController: UIViewController, UI... {` to `class ViewController: UITableViewController {` and change all the tableView functions to be overrides and then set this as the class for your controller in story board. If you're following a tutorial I suggest you start from the beginning to see where you went wrong.

Comment: @Sam_M Thanks! That did it! Yes, I'm following an online course and this was part of a challenge where I had to make a table with map locations where each location will be shown when pressing each table cell. It was just this simple part that stumped me. This part of the process is where I learn the most ;) I really appreciate you help!